# Retry getting result from backend server if certain condition not met

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm tring to get results from server, and retry until i get the right results using rxjs.

**code snippet:**

```
const intervalSub = interval(timeout).subscribe(t => {
  const userSearchSub2 = this.userSearchService.getSearchResult(searchReq).subscribe(xx => {
    if (xx.results) {
      this.dataSource.data = xx.results.map((item: any) => item.values);
      intervalSub.unsubscribe();
    }

    userSearchSub2.unsubscribe();
  });
});
```

Since the inerval is faster than 'getSearchResult', getSearchResult executes several times even if i get my results in the first attempts.

**wanted behavior:**

Stop interval until i check the results of getSearchResult, so getSearchResult do not fire again if i have my results

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a good use case for [exhaustMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/exhaustmap.html).

You have an **outer observable**(the **interval**) and for each emitted value, you would want to make a request, which will create another observable(**inner observable**), but you do not want to go to the next emission of the interval until the current inner observable completes.

```js
let resultsFound = false;

interval(timeout)
    .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => !resultsFound),
        exhaustMap(() => this.userSearchService.getSearchResult(searchReq)),
        map(xx => {
            if (xx.results) {
                resultsFound = true;

                return xx.results.map((item: any) => item.values);
            }

            return null;
        }),
        filter(v => !!v),
    )
    .subscribe(results => console.log(results))
```

Your case is similar to [http polling](https://www.learnrxjs.io/recipes/http-polling.html). Might be worth checking the provided link out.

When `takeWhile`'s predicate function returns **false**(`() => !resultsFound`, `resultsFound = true`), it will **automatically unsubscribe** from the outer observalbe.

Comment: thnaks @Andrei Gătej for our response.
i tried your solution, but still not wotking for me, i have always several backend requests even thow i get my results in the second try. I want to stop requesting the back end until checking the results.

Comment: @a.oubela I have updated my answer. I think exhaustMap is more suitable for this case

Comment: Glad it helped!